# TensorFlow: Simple tf.learn example of multiple GPUs between-graph replication

Tags: tensorflow

I am performing brain surgery on an already-existing TF single-GPU solution to make it work for multiple GPUs.

I've already asked [Simple TensorFlow example loading one copy of a model onto each GPU that's available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46776824/simple-tensorflow-example-loading-one-copy-of-a-model-onto-each-gpu-thats-avail) (thanks Yaroslav!) but I'm having trouble adapting the current code to get the reconciliations of the propagations working across the replicated models.

Looking at [Distributed tensorflow: the difference between In-graph replication and Between-graph replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600321/distributed-tensorflow-the-difference-between-in-graph-replication-and-between) I see @mmry 's answer:

> "in-graph replication" is the first approach that we tried in TensorFlow, and it did not achieve the performance that many users required, so the more complicated "between-graph" approach is the current recommended way to perform distributed training. Higher-level libraries such as tf.learn use the "between-graph" approach for distributed training.

**Where can I find a simple example of tf.learn using copies of a single model for each GPU in a multiple GPU configuration?**

I see that this is also a github issue: https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/696